# Git repository layout for header-only C++ library?

Tags: c++, git

I want to organize a collection of C++ header files in a way that it is easy for me and others to include them in other projects.
It should also be easy to merge changes in those projects to the original files.
For now, I have about 30 header files, about 20 files with unit tests and about 15 files with usage examples which are partly referenced in the Doxygen documentation.
The code is mainly developed on Linux but should be platform-independent (at least theoretically).

My initial idea of organizing the files would be this (suppose the name of the project is `xyz`):

```
xyz/
xyz/examples/
unit_tests/
README
```

Then, the easiest way to use this in another project would be to copy the `xyz/` subdirectory to your own source directory and include the header files like this in your project:

```
#include "xyz/something.h"
```

One advantage of this would be that no paths need to be added in your build system, it should work without changes.

A disadvantage of having the files in a subdirectory is that it's harder to use in `git submodule` and `git subtree`. Especially, `git subtree split` didn't work if only a subdirectory of a repository was used as subtree. (This, however, may become yet another SO question ...)

I've looked at several other (header-only) repositories, and often they have their files in `include/`, `include/xyz/`, `src/` or simply in the root of the repository.

What are your experiences, what would be your preferred layout?
What workflow would you suggest?
Would you use `git submodule` or `git subtree` or something completely different?

Comment: Doesn't having them in the root allow for more flexibility for the users?

Comment: @Hogan: Maybe ... that's what I'm trying to find out. I see two possible shortcomings: (1) it could be confusing with many files in the root directory and (2) there wouldn't be a uniform directory name for `#include`s, people would have to add their own subdirectory or they would need to add a path to their build system.  
Both points may be of minor importance ...

Answer (score 0):

Make your public API header files as a separate repository. Then you could include it as a submodule in your library code and tests. Also your library users will include it as submodule in their repos.

Comment: I didn't make a separation between public API and implementation, all code is in the header files (it's mainly class templates). Therefore I don't see how this would work.

Comment: @Matthias But you say you have unit tests, examples, etc. Move them into another repo if you think that library users do not usually need it.

Comment: However, I think maybe it has more sense to follow `include/xyz` `src`, `examples`, etc layout. Library users usually should add additional include paths, so they use external libraries as `#include <xyz/header.h>` instead of `include "..."`